# how to access contact list in ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

i am a beginner in ionic.I want to access contact list in my app only show contacts. can someone please help me explain me how to access the contact list.I watch tutorial on youtube but this code dosent work. i add this plugin.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

my home.ts file code is..

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Contact,IContactFindOptions,ContactFieldType} from '@ionicnative/contacts';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
    })
    export class HomePage {
     ourtype:ContactFieldType[]=['displayName'];
     contactfound=[];
      constructor(private contacts:Contact,public navctrl:NavController) {
      this.search('');
      
      }
    
     search(q)
     {
       const option:IContactFindOptions= {
         filter:q
         }
    
         this.contacts.find(this.ourtype,option).then(cont =>
          {
            this.contactfound=cont;
          })
     }
    
     onKeyUp(ev)
     {
       this.search(ev.target.value);
     }
  
    }
```

and my html is this

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
   
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-header collapse="condense">
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-searchbar (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let contact of contactfound">
<h2>{{contact?.displayName}}</h2>
<p *ngFor="let num of contact?.phoneNumbers">{{num.value}}</p>

    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

while i run this using these commands

ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova run android --aot

it shows blank screen

Comment: thats expected as `ContactFieldType` is not in the import list on the top of the ts file.

Comment: @francisconeto sir i forgot to add this.but yet it dosent show anything it shows blank screen can you please help me and explain how this code works. thank sin advance

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in your code you are using a camera plugin instead of a contact plugin.

please use the contact plugin

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/contacts